# if $count is a multiple of 3 + 1 in php

Tags: php, math

In php i want to calculate if my count in a foreach loop is a multiple of 3 + 1.

For example if it is 4,7,10,13,16 you get the point.

```
 if( $count % 3 != 0)
```

This is the closest ive come to finding an answer

Comment: `if ($count % 3 != 1)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
if ($count % 3 == 1)
```

Comment: Yes, this is better than my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if ( ($count - 1) % 3 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe this:

```
if ( $count % 3 == 1)
```